# Python Selenium: OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

Game_Pin = input('Enter your PIN: ')
NickNAME = input('Enter your nickname: ')

def Enter_Press():
    selenium.find_element_by_name("Enter").click()


def Kahoot_Spammer(Game_Pin, NickNAME):
    chromedriver = ('C:\\Users\\ovvip\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32.zip')
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
    browser.get('https://kahoot.it/')

    game_pin = selenium.find_element_by_id("Game PIN")
    Name = selenium.find_element_by_id("Nickname")

    game_pin.send_keys(Game_Pin)
    Enter_Press()
    Name.send_keys(NickNAME)
    Enter_Press()




Kahoot_Spammer(Game_Pin, NickNAME)
```

I'm a beginner when it comes to Python so this code probably has quite a few errors within it and could be written more efficiently. Anyway I keep getting this error whenever I run the program been searching for answers for a while now and was wondering if anyone had a clue to what is going on here. I've switched from 64 bit python to 32 bit to see if the chromedriver(which to my knowledge is 32 bit only) was causing any issues with the 64 bit Python, and I got the exact same error. Any help is appreciated.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ovvip/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/KahootSpammer.py", line 27, in <module>
    Kahoot_Spammer(Game_Pin, NickNAME)
  File "C:/Users/ovvip/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/KahootSpammer.py", line 13, in Kahoot_Spammer
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
  File "C:\Users\ovvip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\ovvip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\ovvip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\ovvip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: I believe chromedriver should refer to an EXE file, not a ZIP file.

Answer (score 3):

I assume it is because you didn't unzip the chrome driver first.

Try this to see if it works:

1. `cd` to this folder: `C:\Users\ovvip\Downloads\`
2. unzip the `chromedriver_win32.zip` file
3. in your `Kahoot_Spammer` function, change the file path to the unzipped file: `C:\\Users\\ovvip\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe`

Comment: It fixed most of my problems except now its giving me this error.   FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\ovvip\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32.exe'

Comment: @GoldenMatrices Make sure you use the right file name. Check the name of the `.exe` file in your `download` file. If you download from selenium website, the file name shall be `chromedriver.exe`.